# Voltage multiplier with changed capacitor value ratio

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage-doubler

I want to ask about a voltage multipler.

I understood the voltage doubler. By setting the capacitor values ​​of the two capacitors to the same value and setting the voltage doubler circuit, we can obtain a voltage twice as high as the existing voltage.

Without adding capacitors or resistors, can we create three or four times the voltage (voltage multipler) by changing only the capacitor values (ratio) of the two capacitors?

Comment: No. Add a stage for a tripler, another for a quadrupler, etc.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thank you! Then, do you know that how it's change when change two capacitor's ratio?

Comment: The output impedance will be dominated by the smaller C and you'll see less output voltage into any significant load.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the ratio of the capacitors doesn't change the voltage multiplier ratio.

A single stage "voltage doubler" delivers about twice the output voltage that you would get from a simple rectifier.  That is, the DC output is approximately the peak to peak voltage of the AC input.  The "doubler" part comes from the fact that you get double the DC of a simple rectifier.

If you have an AC input of 100 volts peak to peak, then the output of the doubler will be about 100VDC (minus the diode voltage drops.)

As you can see the "ratio" is no ratio at all.  The capacitors have no influence on it.

Each stage of a voltage doubler adds the same voltage as the preceding stages.  One stage is double the simple rectifier output.  Two stages is four times the simple rectifier voltage.  Three stages is six times the simple rectifier voltage, and so on.

Where the capacitors matter is in the impedance of the voltage multiplier.  The capacitors have to pass what ever AC frequency you are using.  Since capacitors have a frequency dependent impedance, the amount of current you can draw from the output depends greatly on the capacitors.

Assuming that all the capacitors are the same, then you can (approximately) calculate the impedance using this equation:

$$ Z = \frac {1}{2 \pi fC} (4n^3 + 3n^2 - n) $$

Where:

1. \$Z\$ is in ohms
2. \$f\$ is the AC frequency in hertz
3. \$C\$ is the capacitor value in farads
4. \$n\$ is the number of multiplier stages.

As you can see, the impedance goes up rather quickly as the number of stages increases.

This equation will tell you the output voltage, provided you also know how much current the load will draw:

$$ E_{out} = 2nE_{pk} - \frac {I_{load}}{2 \pi fC} (4n^3 + 3n^2 - n) - 2nV_{f}$$

Where:

1. \$E_{out}\$ the output voltage
2. \$f\$ is the AC frequency in hertz
3. \$C\$ is the capacitor value in farads
4. \$n\$ is the number of multiplier stages
5. \$I_{load}\$ is the load current in amperes
6. \$V_{f}\$ is the forward voltage of the diodes.
7. \$E_{pk}\$ is the peak voltage of the AC (note: just the peak, not the peak to peak)

Large capacitors have a lower impedance so you can get more current from the output if you use large capacitors.

You can get the same effect by using a higher frequency.

You can also combine the two - use larger capacitors at a higher frequency.

The main problem with high voltage multipliers is that large value capacitors are insanely expensive at high voltage.  They are also huge.

---

I had something of a go around with [voltage multipliers](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/diode-capacitors-volts-pt7) last year.

Comment: Thanks JRE for confirming in more detail, what I said, you want all caps equal to achieve best impedance ratio and max N stages at the expense of 1st stage diode current peak cycles on startup

Comment: "number of multiplier stages" = number of diodes = number of capacitors?

Comment: @endolith:  A stage consists of two diodes and two capacitors.

Comment: So for a "voltage tripler", n would be 1.5?

Comment: A voltage tripler uses a slightly different circuit.  The ones the equations above apply to are only valid for a half wave Cockcroft-Walton voltage multiplier in which each stage adds the same DC voltage to the output.  The voltage at each stage is twice the voltage of a simple rectifier - hence the name.

Comment: I'm not seeing what the difference is, can you explain? https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cockcroft_Walton_voltage_multiplier_circuit.svg  https://instrumentationtools.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/instrumentationtools.com_diodes-voltage-tripler.png for example. (This Cockcroft-Walton would be a quadrupler, right?  So n = 2?)

Comment: Yes, the output is four time the output of a simple rectifier.  If you add another stage then the output is six times the output of a simpler rectifier.

Comment: @JRE So for the "voltage tripler" shown, n would be 1.5?  :)

Comment: I don't know.  That circuit is different, so the equations above don't apply to it.

Comment: @JRE In what way is it different?

Answer (score 0):

It is not the ratio of C that multiplies , rather the clamp DC added to the Vpp .. triplets etc cascade more diode caps

### Pro Bono info

There are limits as diode drops (insignif for HV) and cap ESR adds so attenuation from leakage limits multiplier.

More accurately it ought to be called a Clamp Adder as Vpp is added to each stage. But for 1 stage of 2 diodes and 2 caps  it is x2.  , or N/2 +1 multiply Vpp input for N diodes,Caps or X stages + 1 input multiplier * load/leakage attenuation

Somewhat like inductive transformers, C ratio is called a capacitive transformer so you get /2 boost on each cycle peak until it reaches ,maximum (unless loaded)

C transformers are used in some HV bushings to divide HVAC down from 1 pF say to 10nF is 1e4:1 voltage divider for sensing on AC without DC load.